# REGEX: Trying to create a reg. exp. that can find a string in the referrers host name

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to create a JavaScript regular expression that can find a keyword in the referrers host name. It cannot be in the file path, just the host name. So... these should pass:

```
http://keyword.com/
http://www.keyword.com/
http://keyword.example.com/
http://examplekeyword.com/
```

But these should not:

```
http://example.com/keyword
http://example.com/?q=keyword
http://example.com/example/keyword.php
```

I also unsure how to create the regex. I've seen **var re = new regex('actual regex');** and also **mystring.search('actual regex');** . Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: In the `search` syntax, you need to give it a RegExp object. A string will be accepted, but we'll only be searching for a string, not a regular expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
^http://[^/]*keyword
```

Will match if the keyword is present. What it returns is kinda odd (`http://keyword` for `http://keyword.com`), but it's the least complex you can do.

If you're interested in the full hostname being returned,

```
^http://[^/]*keyword[^/]*
```

Returns `http://thekeywordexists.com` for `http://thekeywordexists.com/foo`.

There are a number of ways to use regular expressions in Javascript. [Regular-Expressions.info's Javascript page](http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascript.html) is likely a good resource for this. (Performance tip: create the RegExp object once and make it a variable, rather than creating it every time you use it :o)

Comment: That also matches `http://somekeyword.com/`, although I don't know if that is acceptable.

Comment: @WoLpH - I'm not sure I understand. `http://examplekeyword.com/` is equivalent, and lists as a test that should pass.

Comment: Additionally, the assumption is that we should match keywordexample too.... which the above does.

Comment: Indeed, I overlooked that example. In that case it's correct :)

Answer (score 0):

I believe that this does what you want:

```
/^http:\/\/[^\/]*keyword\./.test('http://www.keyword.com')
```

A little explanation:

- start with `http` followed by `://` (`^http:\/\/`)
- follwed by everything besides `/`
- followed by `keyword` followed by a `.`

Comment: Yes, I overlooked that example. In that case it's even simpler.